# RMI applet is making requests on random ports and blocked consequently

Tags: java, random, applet, rmi

I have set up RMI system successfully on local ubuntu srver.
Registry port 1099 and remote object export on 1100(fixed by calling super(1100)) 
Now I am trying to make it work on Ubuntu over internet with a public IP.
I could bind service properly with public ip.But the client applet is trying to connect to ubuntu server at random ports.
Below is the error thrown by client applet:

```
// Exception  
network: Connecting public-ip:1100 with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting public-ip/cgi-bin/java-rmi.cgi?forward=1099 with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting public-ip:3733 with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting public-ip:3721 with proxy=DIRECT 
 //   
java.rmi.ConnectException: 
Connection refused to host: public-ip; nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(Unknown Source)Source) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) 
...
```

I have only 2 ports open on server, i.e., 1099(registry) and 1100(export). How can I fix ports in applet requests such that it does always connect server on same open port?

Another issue.
As I have bound service on public IP i.e. //public-ip:1099/ServiceName, a job running on server to send message to clinets is not able to make request to RMI service. public-ip URL does not work on same machine,i.e., server.Do you think I should use fixed socket factory?If so please give me code snippet and guide me how i can set it up.

```
//Exception   
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: public-ip; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:128)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:194)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:148)
    at $Proxy5.getUserID(Unknown Source)
    at rmi.source.xxxxxx$JobScheduler.run(xxxxServerImpl.java:293)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:337)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:198)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:180)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:146)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: A tip:  If it is related to or written in Java, add the Java tag.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I fix ports in applet requests such that it does always connect server on same open port?

Export your remote objects on a fixed port number.

> Do you think I should use fixed socket factory?

No, you need to set the `java.rmi.server.hostname` system property.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.I did export object on server implementation (extending UnicastRemoteObject) contructor by calling super(1100) Also I have set java.rmi.server.hostname property with public IP on server as well as client applet.Did rebind on public IP But getting following exception now:

Comment: java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
 java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: P.B.L.I.C-I.P; nested exception is: 
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
 at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:353)
 at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
 at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

Comment: @Dan Are you getting that from inside or outside the LAN? Or both? RMI's possibly invalid presumption is that there is a 'most public' IP address that everybody can use, hence the java.rmi.server.hostname design.

Comment: client is outside LAN.Using windows client over different internet connection with a public-ip.I am trying to connect from a pc in this windows LAN to Ubuntu rmi server on different internet connection. I have port forwarded both 1099 and 1100(fixed exported port) on this windows client NAT too.Windows client pc's have fixed IP's 192.168.1.X and public IP 122.166.X.YYY I also tried by giving hostname in clinet applet these ip addresses.Still no luck.Where am I gone wrong? @EJP

Comment: java.rmi.server.hostname is set *at the server.*

Comment: I did set hostname property in server.Now I am getting following exception: java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
 java.rmi.ConnectIOException: Exception creating connection to: 192.168.1.2; nested exception is: 
 java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
 at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:353)  @EJP

Comment: Above IP on fail is local ip of a client pc on LAN which is connected to internet having a public IP.I am able to ping to the windws client public IP form Ubuntu RMI server which is on different internet connection.RMI server on ubuntu is failing to connect back to client PC-192.168.1.2 on windows LAN.How can i fix this issue?Thanks @EJP

Comment: @Dan You need to set java.rmi.server.hostname, at the server JVM, before exporting any remote objects, including the Registry, and you need to set it to the most public IP address the server host has, the one that is accessible to everybody (see discussion above).

Comment: Thank you for the reply.I did as you said.Now my rmi system is working one way.Cleint successfully calls method on server and gets computed result.But server is failing to send message to client from a running job at server.My client pc is in a LAN connected to internet.The cient's internet server has public IP too.I guess ubuntu rmi server is not able to locate the client in the LAN hence throwing above exception.what do you think? @EJP

Comment: @Dan I misspoke. You may need to set java.rmi.server.hostname as above at any JVM that exports remote objects. If your client exports callbacks it is a server from RMI's point of view when those callbacks are being called.In each case you set it to the value you want clients to use when calling you: *not* to a value you want to use when executing a call yourself.

Comment: Ok.Tested my rmi application from my laptop running windows7(USB internet) as client.I Didnt set hostname on client but on server.rmi-server(ubuntu)-client(windows)works great!Now issue is with a pc connected to LAN having local fixed IP 192.168.1.xx .Following exception received: java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is:
java.rmi.ConnectIOException:Exception creating connection to: 192.168.1.xx; nested exception is:java.net.NoRouteToHostException:No route to host at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:353) @EJP

Comment: Actually,a push from rmi server to client is failing.My client is on different internet connection + LAN .Can you please help me solve it?Thank you @EJP

Comment: @Dan If the client is behind a firewall and exports callbacks you *must* set `java.rmi.server.hostname`, to *its* 'most public' IP address.

Comment: Sorry to bother you over and again.I am very sad i couldnt get it work.Worried my effort would go waste:( I have set public ip of client in hostname property of client applet.now i am getting different exception. java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
 java.rmi.ConnectIOException: Exception creating connection to: client-public-ip; nested exception is: 
 java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out @EJP

Comment: @Dan So your server can't communicate with your client. Can you ping the client from the server?

Comment: Exactly.Pinging public IP of my LAN client from ubuntu-rmi-server is failing.However,browser loads page http://client-public-ip/ on rmi server machine.Client internet server having public-ip runs IIS7.This windows pc runs other web applications successfully accessible over public-ip.How can I fix this issue? Thanks @EJP

Comment: @Dan The question at the moment is what IP address is inside the stub of the client callback. Can you print it out? (toString() will do.) That will show you what IP address the server is trying to use to connect to for the callback. If it isn't the client's 'most public' IP address, you aren't setting `java.rmi.server.hostname` at the client correctly, or early enough (i.e. before you have exported any remote objects, including the Registry, from the client).

Comment: stub: Proxy[MyServer,RemoteObjectInvocationHandler[UnicastRef [liveRef: [endpoint:[ubuntu-server-public-ip:1100](remote),objID:[-2628b2d5:1399cf3cb85:-7fff, 1200669213386122078]]]]] I am not exporting any obj in client side.just doing look up server.The same set up works one time on my laptop(didnt work on my lan having public ip) when i login into my web application to which rmi system is integrated but it's not working when i navigate pages. @EJP

Comment: Hi Now I did registry,export on client side too.The IP address inside client stub shows:  client-stub clientImpl[UnicastServerRef [liveRef: [endpoint:[client-public-ip:1100](local),objID:[-51c9452f:139b002d4f2:-7ffe, 69509874636995575]]]]  
 java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
 java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: client-public-ip; nested exception is: 
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
 at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:353)  could you please help me? @EJP

Comment: Iam accessing rmi server from LAN with internet server running IIS7 on 80.I have opened ports 1099 and 1100.I am not able to crack this problem:(

Comment: Hi @EJP just read about you on few blogs that you are a great guy.Could you please help me solve above issue? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am back! I've caught hold of culprit's hand.I did port forward to my pc's IP address on client side NAT and successful in getting response from ubuntu server behind NAT running a job!Another issue is that,As Iam exporting client remote obj onto public IP of local LAN,my pc's failing to connect itself using this public ip but successfully connects ubuntu rmi-server outside LAN.Hope now you can help me out @EJP

Comment: Guys,I was able to make RMI work by using Dr Dob's technique,i.e., "hole punching"